# Does istio ingress controller support session affinity

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I saw some post said only nginx ingress support session affinity and I couldn't find example of istio ingress supporting session affinity.
So my question is, does istio nginx support session affinity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do so [using a `DestinationRule`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/).

An example for a sticky session can be found in the [LoadBalancerSettings section](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-ratings
spec:
  host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      consistentHash:
        httpCookie:
          name: user
          ttl: 0s
```

Here is also a somewhat older post that uses `networking.istio.io/v1alpha3` as the `apiVersion`, however, the explanation is still valid: https://dev.to/peterj/what-are-sticky-sessions-and-how-to-configure-them-with-istio-1e1a